# Azure Function + OpenId Connect = 500 on callback

Tags: azure, azure-functions, openid-connect

I have an azure function (nodejs) and through the Authentication tab, I'm adding an OpenID Connect identity provider. After filling in details, when hitting the function (hosting a web page, so I have redirect enabled), it take the user to the openid connect provider's login page, and upon signing on, they get redirected back to the azure function as expected:

```
https://[appname].azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/[provider-name]/callback?code=[code]&state=redir%3D%252F
```

However, at that point, it gets an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. There's no details in logstream, or host logs as to what the error is. Logs also doesn't find any exceptions in the last 24 hours.

Is there something I'm missing? How can I start debugging this?

Comment: have you be able to resolve this issue? 
I am getting the same error and there is indeed no clues in the log about the source of the problem. I suspect the firewall though...

Comment: Unfortunately no... resorted to using passportjs openidconnect and handled auth app side. Later on we did find that the redirect url set up with the provider was a bit different (relative vs absolute) so perhaps it's related to that. We had the passportjs stuff working, so didn't test afterwards.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, and yes, it was the Firewall. After testing the same scenario with an IDP which was reachable via the public internet, everything started working. Thanks for the hint, @Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

This might occur as described if there is a mistake / mismatch in specifying the client id or client secret in Azure. If you are getting this error, that's the first place I'd start -- double and triple check them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-openid-connect